# Android Studio keeps giving a file not found exception. Not sure why

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an Android app in Android Studio. I'm trying to get the app to load an .xlsx file. But whenever I do so it gives me a "File not found" exception.

The file is stored in the folder that Android Studio itself created when i selected "Directory" and chose "Assets". I selected the "src/main/assets" folder.

In the screenshots below you can see the error I am getting, the folder structure, the code I use to call the file and a notification I noticed that pops up when debugging. I think the last picture with the notification may not be relevant for this error but I included it just in case it might be relevant.

What have I tried so far?

- Testing with another file. So I have tested with filename and filename2. Respectively a .xlsx file and a .png file.
- I have restarted Android Studio.
- I have cleaned the project, clicked make project and rebuilt the project.
- I have tried renaming the file so it has all lower case letters.

Any suggestions as to why my Android studio does not find this file?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I selected the "src/main/assets" folder" -- the screenshot suggests that you wound up with `src/androidTest/assets`. It has "(androidTests)" after your filename. Personally, I never use that Android view -- I click the drop-down above the project tree and choose "Project", for an actual honest-to-goodness look at where the files are.

Comment: Yea I was thinking the same. But if I right clicked again it afterwards showed me the "androidTest" option. And if I clicked that then it just pointed to the exact same folder. Same happened if I selected the "debug" version of the assets folder. All 3 just made the same folder and same location. What I mean is, I have tried main, test and debug.

Comment: Perhaps use your development machine's file manager, or the Project view (see updated comment above), and see where the files really are on the filesystem.

Comment: Great thinking! I think that could solve it.

Comment: It worked! I now get a different error due to the file not being read as it should. But at least now it finds the file. Thanks very much. I resolved it by manually moving the file in Windows Explorer. In Android Studio it looked as though there was just one folder. But in Windows Explorer there were in fact multiple folders. So I moved it from AndroidTest to Main manually there.

Answer (score 1):

As CommonsWare suggested in a comment I could try look outside Android Studio. And it turned out that despite there only appearing one "Assets" folder in Android Studio there were 4 folders. The files were in "androidTest" and i moved them to "main". Then it found the file.

[image]

Comment: CommonsWare is a true living legend.